# sed replace string from file with content from another file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to replace string from file with content from another file

File 1: T1.txt

```
TEXT1  
TEXT2  
TEXT3  
TEXT4
```

File 2:
T2.txt

```
Line with PLACEHOLDER
Line with PLACEHOLDER
Line with PLACEHOLDER
Line with PLACEHOLDER
```

I want to replace "PLACEHOLDER" string from "File 2" with all contents from "File 1", no matter if it create new file or change in existing file.

I tried :-

```
sed -i -e '/PLACEHOLDER/ r T2.sql' -e s/PLACEHOLDER// T1.sql
```

not working not sure why

Comment: You want to paste the contents of File 1 multiple times into different places in File 2?

Comment: @ceving , yes correct , please suggest

Answer (score 0):

This will insert a newline before the included text, and does not handle text that may follow PLACEHOLDER:

```
sed -e '/PLACEHOLDER/{ s///; rT1.txt
}'  T2.txt
```

To avoid the additional newline and to handle PLACEHOLDER in the middle of a line, you could do:

```
perl -MFile::Slurp -pe 'BEGIN{$r=read_file("T1.txt")} s/PLACEHOLDER/$r/g' T2.txt
```

You probably (almost certainly) can make `sed` do the inline substitution of  a multiline value, but `sed` really is line oriented and any such solution would require more gymnastics than using enhanced sed (aka, perl).